dynamic atomic change in Mongodb, avoiding race conditions
We have these objects for which we want to retain user-defined order. For example:
class Book:
    id: ObjectId
    order: int


class ClubBookRanking:
    books: list[Book]

Before you suggest, relying on the list order doesn't work here. It just shifts the problem.
We store these objects in mongo. There are two kinds of operations we need to perform here.

Add a new book: this should append to the end of the list (order should be equal to list length when including the new item)
User re-ordering: the book must change it's order value, and all books that come after it must also have their order updated.

These situations are both vulnerable to race conditions. My instinct is to attempt to do these things in complex atomic transactions. I am assuming that mongo will execute atomic transaction sequentially and race conditions will therefore be avoided (ala redis).
Does anyone know the best way of handling this? We do use Atlas, so we can use their functionality.
Edit:
The books have a uuid

How are these classes stored in the database?

Just as the JSON equivalent:
{
books: [{id: 1234, order: 1}]
}

In that case the books array contains the orders, so a simple update would be atomic.  Just change the order for every book in the array, and then use updateOne, or the equivalent, which will be an atomic update.

This question is about software design, not a specific programming problem. Read about MongoDB's Concurrency strategies. Specifically, "Writes to a single document occur either in full or not at all, and clients always see consistent data." For handling ordering either with an order field or by maintaining the list order, take a look at these answers (disclaimer: mine) or similar SO questions. Update pipelines are effectively atomic.

@joe If you update the value for every book in the array by setting a static value and then perform a transaction, you are vulnerable to a race condition. Between the time that you calculated all those order numbers, someone else may have mutated the object changing the order numbers. The calculation and update need to be together in an atomic transaction

To elaborate what as Joe said, you can really benefit from guaranteed order of elements in an array and atomicity of updates on document level.
ClubBookRanking is a single document, and all books are ordered within the books array.
All you need is to ensure no concurrent updates to this document which is easily resolved with revisions, e.g. see how mongoose implemented it with versionKey https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/e359b99e0d1a15669143363855207660aa508fb9/docs/guide.md#option-versionkey
Essentially you add a monotonically incremented revision number to ClubBookRanking, which you increment on each update. In pseudocode:
const cbr = db.ClubBookRanking.findOne(); //the document
const __v = cbr.__v;  //the revision number
reorder(cbr.book); // reshuffle the books
const result = db.ClubBookRanking.updateOne(
    {
        _id: cbr._id,   // filter by unique id
        __v: __v        // and only when revision didn't change since we read the document
    }, {
        $set: {books: cbr.books}, // the new order
        $inc:{__v:1}              // increment the revision
    })
    if (result.nModified < 1 ) {
         throw new Error("Concurrent update") 
    }
);

Here we try an optimistic update, assuming there is no concurrent updates, so that updateOne updates at most 1 document. If there was a concurrent update, the __v won't match the filter, and no updates will happen - result.nModified will be 0.
Now it's up to you how to resolve the conflict - you can do something smart by fetching the new revision and trying to re-apply the reordering to the latest revision programmatically, or through it back to the user saying that someone else update the order quicker than them, and ask to review and reorder.

+1 to maintaining a revisionId for the data to avoid non-concurrent updates. It's the easiest way to avoid separate updates based on old-data. Only the first one submitted gets processed and the others fail. Of course, conflict resolution is up to the implementation. Though, I would call it revisionId or revision since __v is commonly used for the schema version, rather than the data version. Also - for refence to others - revisionId/revisionKey can be anything, not just incremental integers - so random hash, ObjectIds, timestamps (avoid), etc. I prefer something non-predictable.

@aneroid are you sure about __v? The document behind the link explicitly says it's intended for document versioning. In my answer I just shortened the algorithm described there to the bare minimum tailored to the OPs question. Happy to be proven wrong tho.

regarding incremental numbers vs anything else - it's the simplest and most reliable way. Any crypto/random algorithms are quite expensive and must be implemented on all clients (things like manual updates from mongosh) whilst $inc is implemented on the DB side, is consistent, and requires only constant inputs. I appreciate that personal preferences is a major factor that outweighs any other arguments, but I fail to see any objective advantages of "non-predictable" value really.  Are there any?

Yup, you are right - the Mongo tutorials use schema_version. Some vids call it version. Yes, the docs state that __v is used for object/data versioning. Thanks!

Non-predictable values: The only advantage, the main one, is not being able to be gamed. Say it was predictable and via an API request, and the form submit uses __v as a param and it fails. It's easy to just increment and retry. Whereas a non-predictable revision forces getting the updated data from the DB/backend. (Of course junk data can be sent regardless of which type is used.)

I was leaning towards a generation number like in GCloud Storage or VersionID in AWS S3. For GCP, the generation number is non-predictable but the metageneration is incremental per object. Hence, the generation method is my preference. Of course, you're right about $inc really just being the easiest if gaming-non-concurrent updates is not an issue and if it's only to prevent mistaken non-concurrent updates.

@aneroid, I see you point, and yes, if the revision have to be exposed on the API level, it would require additional complexity. The cloud providers don't have a choice, but for private API the revision number should not be exposed. It belongs to serverside logic to resolve concurrent updates only. Clients should not care about it really.
